# why does in VScode this heart ❤ emoji give me gray color instead of red , but why all other emojis are ok?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, colors, emoji

here is my codepen link. I can't make the heart emoji red.

https://codepen.io/Touraf/pen/MWVoyzW

This where the emoji is-

### The Basic Language of the Web: HTML

```
      <img
        src="IMG/laura-jones.jpg"
        alt="Headshot of Laura Jones"
        height="50"
        width="50"
      />

      <p id="author">
        Posted by <strong>Laura Jones</strong> on Monday, June 21st 2027
      </p>

      <img
        src="IMG/post-img.jpg"
        alt="HTML code on a screen"
        width="500"
        height="200"
        class="post-img"
      />
      <button>❤ Like</button>
    </header>
```

Comment: Why should it be red? You don't have any CSS to change it from the default colour.

Comment: The code Im learning from- it appeared red in there. but in mine its gray.

Comment: you could just use this ❤️ instead

Comment: You must have missed the part where the code you are learning from had some CSS in it.

Comment: i tried it but nothing happened @Lukas

Comment: maybe i missed it. but i checked the video twice. still nothing unique he did. @Quentin

Comment: Note: you can add a variant selector to "force" coloured or just "black" emoji so: VS16 (= \uFE0F) for colour and VS15 (=\FE0E) for black and white.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your css and it should work

```
button:first-letter {
  color: red;
}
```